# GZWeb not showing extra robot model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I've installed gzweb, and configured the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH variable to include my custom models prior to running the deploy script.

I'm running a script from the PX4 folks to produce a quadcopter running inside a gazebo simulation. It shows up just fine in gzclient, but I can't get the graphic for the model to show in GZWeb. The object is present - I can select it in the object selector, it's just like it has no graphics/textures.

It DOES show up in my gzweb http/assets folder. Ideas? It's a basic iris quadcopter model...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13249/gzweb-not-showing-extra-robot-model/) by [srees](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2391/srees/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-05-11**:
Maybe it is related to this issue? https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gzweb/issues/78/spawning-the-pr2-robot-vs-inserting-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

chapulina's comment was in the right direction, but not quite there. The files were missing, even though I had included them in the deploy. I copied them into the assets folder and it fixed it.

---

Originally posted by [srees](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2391/srees/) with karma: 13 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0